# SSIS customised Slow Changing Dimension

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008

i have 50 customer and i am asked to design a SSIS package
to handle the Slow Changing Dimension.

i have designed the entire package for it.

The real challenge for me.

How can i make sure if any new customer file arrived for the first time,
it will load to the table Warehouse and not in the staging table.

that means **latest file** from customer should be always load into **staging table**
and **oldest file** which arrived for the **first time** will be in **warehouse table.**

May be it looks broad question, but i am badly need of expert advise.

I am pretty new to SSIS , May anyone please share your expertise.

Thanks

Comment: Different customer have unique customerid......

Comment: Normally _every_ file arrives in staging. Then any differences between staging and the dimension are applied to the dimension. When the next file arrives, the staging table is truncated and the process repeats. I don't understand your question.